# page should not be refresh on fire enter event with bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have this Javascript code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('body').on('click','#submit-btn',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('ok');
    });

    $("#name").keyup(function(event){
        if(event.keyCode == 13){
            $("#submit-btn").trigger("click");
        }
      });

    });
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lr3taznx/39/

On click submit button it's working fine but on enter using `Keyup` event it's refreshing the page and I don't want to refresh the page on `enter` event.

Comment: Ok. Ok. But, **Where is your code** (which you tried from your end).

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
 $("#name").keyup(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        $("#submit-btn").trigger("click");
    }
  });
```

With,

```
$("#module_name").keyup(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        $("#submit-btn").trigger("click");
    }
  });
```

Because, you have initialize event on wrong object, means $("#name") is id selector and id is "module_name".

Comment: good job parth but why this also not working --

new link -- http://jsfiddle.net/Lr3taznx/41/

Answer (score 1):

Change your click event to submit event of form:

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('body').on('submit','#module_form',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('ok');
           $('#myModal').modal('hide');
        });

        $("#name").keyup(function(event){
            if(event.keyCode == 13){
              alert('ok');
                $("#submit-btn").trigger("click");
            }
          });

        });
```

& the submit button to a type submit

```
<button type="submit" id="submit-btn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zk48vvfd/

Answer (score 0):

You only should prevent of the default behaviour of the `keyup event`.

So your code should be

```
  $("#name").keyup(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      if(event.keyCode == 13){
         $("#submit-btn").trigger("click");
      }
  });
```